# Get the media buttons on my bluetooth headset working with Spotify on OS X

Tags: macos, bluetooth, applescript, osx-mavericks, spotify

I just bought a Parrot Zik, which is a pair of bluetooth headphones with volume control, play/pause and next-prev buttons. (Or gestures, as they come with the Zik).

The phones work beautifully with OS X, but I would like to be able to use the play/pause and next-prev with Spotify.

I've seen the [similar question on this site](https://superuser.com/questions/554489/how-can-i-remap-a-play-button-keypress-from-a-bluetooth-headset-on-os-x), but the answer didn't help me, either because it is not entirely up to date and incompatible with Mavericks, or because Spotify lacks support.

The best thing I could think of is to map the bluetooth media keys to media function keys that are on my mac's keyboard, they all work with spotify, VLC and virtually every other app I every tried it with.

One option would be using AppleScript. I think at least Spotify can be scripted to do these things using AppleScript. But better would be a script that simply does the mapping of these events to the media keys. The question would be: how to write such a resident script that triggers by pressing my bluetooth headphone's media keys?

Otherwise, is there an app or plug-in of some sort that allows me to do the mapping?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this: https://github.com/jguice/mac-bt-headset-fix. Works for me, and I'm using a Parrot Zik on Mavericks.

The only issue is that iTunes still opens with headset gestures.

Comment: great tool indeed...
don't fprget to install https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/streamkeys/ekpipjofdicppbepocohdlgenahaneen/related?hl=en