# How can I mute my microphone while wearing a Bluetooth headset on macOS Big Sur?

Tags: mac, bluetooth, headset

I own a bluetooth headset(Bose QC) which is connected to my MacBook and would like to mute and unmute my microphone during a call by touching "play/pause" or another headphone key.

This should be possible by remaping one of the media keys [with karabiner](https://github.com/pqrs-org/Karabiner-Elements/issues/2398) or triggering some [apple script automation](https://medium.com/macoclock/how-in-the-bleep-do-i-mute-my-mic-anywhere-on-macos-d2fa1185b13) with it.
But it seems like the keystrokes are invisible to the karabiner and apple automator.

Is there a way to detect pressing play/pause on my headset?

There seemed to be [some way](https://superuser.com/questions/554489/how-can-i-remap-a-play-button-keypress-from-a-bluetooth-headset-on-os-x) or [another](https://superuser.com/questions/674900/get-the-media-buttons-on-my-bluetooth-headset-working-with-spotify-on-os-x) on older versions of mac OS, but the solutions seem to be outdated.

Comment: If you're unable to find a software-based solution, plugging a dummy jack (or any other 3.5mm jack)  into the microphone jack disables it at the hardware level.

Comment: Did you ever find anything to do this?  Have a pair of QC35s and I hate having to run back to my computer to unmute

Comment: Re: plugging in a dead microphone -- the goal here is to mute/unmute mic while on a call but not physically at your computer.  If sitting at your computer, you don't need to plug in a dead microphone to mute.. you can just click the mute button.