# headphones play/pause button as push to talk in discord (or remap this button to sth else)

Tags: macos, discord

Is there a way to make play/pause button on headphones to act as push to talk shortcut in discord app? Or to remap somehow this button to another shortcut, that can be used for example in discord.
Someone tried this on mac?

Comment: What model of headphones?

Comment: standard earpods added to iphone: https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MNHF2AM/A/earpods-with-35-mm-headphone-plug

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing that currently supports this on a Mac (unless perhaps it is rooted).

However, if you are serious about doing this, your best bet is to write a listener as described [here](https://superuser.com/questions/554489/how-can-i-remap-a-play-button-keypress-from-a-bluetooth-headset-on-os-x), but instead of mapping it to standard controls, map it to your discord text-to-talk shortcut.

Hope this helps,

Comment: Your link does not work, but I found it: https://superuser.com/questions/554489/how-can-i-remap-a-play-button-keypress-from-a-bluetooth-headset-on-os-x

Comment: I even found this question before but I didn't find this Karabiner app. Ok so I will have to make hands dirty...